# Laravel & Chatter - Where to specify Base URI for Links and Assets

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I am new to Laravel. I installed the [Chatter](https://github.com/thedevdojo/chatter) forum package.

My directory structure on shared hosting is:

```
├── public_html/
│   ├── index.html (non-Laravel)
│   └── assets
└── project_name/
    ├── public
    ├── index.php
```

When I visit http://www.mywebsite.com/project_name/ it shows me the page with the message "Laravel is a framework so it doesn't have a index page", and redirects me to http://www.mywebsite.com/project_name/public

After a lot of effort, I saw that the Chatter forum package was installed at http://www.mywebsite.com/project_name/public/forums

However, it failed to load the CSS and js, and permalinks are generated as "http://www.mywebsite.com/forums/discussion/general..." instead of "http://www.mywebsite.com/community/forums/discussion/general..."

1. Why does Laravel even have a "public" folder - seeing so many questions on Stackoverflow makes me wonder how does it even help?
2. How do I get rid of it, without using .htaccess in the root (My .htaccess at root already has some code in it which pretty much would disturb the other parts of the website.
3. I have tried renaming server.php as index.php in root Laravel folder as mentioned in one of the top-rated answers here on Stackoverflow, but that doesn't help.

Ideally, I'd like Chatter accessible at "http://www.mywebsite.com/community/forums"

Comment: The public folder in Laravel is where your server's DocumentRoot should point to.

Comment: Does that mean if I need to install Laravel, I cannot have any other frameworks installed at other subdomains/subdirectories ?